# Why aren't my all my included php files showing? (CSS navigation tabs)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, json

I have a php document that uses css navigation tabs to display 3 different files

```
<div id="Tum" class="w3-container training">
<h2>TUM</h2>
<?php include("tum.php");  ?>
</div>

<div id="Atol" class="w3-container training" style="display:none">
<h2>ATÖLYE</h2>
<?php include("atol2.php");  ?>
</div>

<div id="Uzman" class="w3-container training" style="display:none">
<h2>UZMANLIK</h2>
<?php include("uzman.php");  ?>
</div>
```

My test url is [here](http://test.alacakseyler.com/facebookeventtest/events2.php)

The first file loads fine - tum.php - however the next two do not. I think this is because they are almost identical. The three files pull facebook event data using json then populate in echoed html. I can't work out why the other 2 files are not being populated.

As I say the 3 included files are all similar, the only difference is:

```
$isMatch_atol = preg_match('/Atölyesi/', $name_atol);
if($isMatch_atol){
```

I use the pregmatch to filter the results from the json. Each individual page works if loaded alone.

I'm stuck as to why this is not working. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility that the code in atol2 and uzman could be broken?

Maybe try replacing their code with a simple "echo 123;". If that works, then you know the actual include is not the issue.

Comment: Hi @MatthewLymer - the pages load fine independently for example http://test.alacakseyler.com/facebookeventtest/atol2.php

Comment: But yes, if i replace the file with a file with a simple echo, the echo does load :/

Comment: So you need to debug the included files code - something there is broken.

Comment: @OfirBaruch damn yeah.. I was redeclaring a function over and over - PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare sortFunction()

Comment: Well.. at least you've found it :)

Comment: I need to learn that the error log _is_ useful! Thanks for all of your replies.

Comment: Glad you found it! Sounded like it had to be a break as opposed to an include issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each 3 files had a declare function, which only needed to be declared once, that function being my date sorting:

```
function sortFunction($a,$b){
    if ($a['start_time'] == $b['start_time']) return 0;
    return strtotime($a['start_time']) - strtotime($b['start_time']);
}
```

Erasing that function from every file included after the first included file solved the problem.